# Set custom process name for JAR application with launch4j?

Tags: java, jar, launch4j

I'm trying to set a custom process name for a jar application I am using, so that in the Task Manager, instead of it being shown as Java (TM) Platform SE Binary, it will display the application name and chosen icon.
Have tried to wrap the jar as an exe file with launch4j, but cannot seem to find a way to change the process name with this. From what I can tell from google searches, it seems like it may no longer be supported, however, the posts I have found a quite dated, so it could have changed.

Anyone know if there is a way to archieve this with launch4j, or perhaps with another free tool? [image: Process Name]